# Looping over different python dictionaries - wrong results?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using Python 2.7, btw..

Let's say I have a couple directories that I want to create dictionaries for. The files in each of the directories are named YYYYMMDD.hhmmss and are all different, and the size of each directory is different:

```
 path1 = /path/to/folders/to/make/dictionaries
 dir1 = os.listdir(path1)
```

I also have another static directory that will have some files to compare

```
 gpath1 = /path/to/static/files
 gdir1 = os.listdir(gpath1)
 dir1_file_list = [datetime.strptime(g, '%Y%m%d.%H%M%S') for g in gdir1]
```

So I have a static directory of files in gdir2, and I now want to loop through each directory in dir1 and create a unique dictionary. This is the code:

```
 for i in range(0,len(dir1)):
    path2 = path1 + "/" + dir1[i]
    dir2 = os.listdir(path2)
    dir2_file_list = [datetime.strptime(r, '%Y%m%d.%H%M%S') for r in dir2]

    # Define a dictionary, and initialize comparisons
    dict_gr = []
    dict_gr = dict()
    for dir1_file in dir1_file_list:
        dict_gr[str(dir1_file)] = []

        # Look for instances within the last 5 minutes
        for dir2_file in dir2_file_list:
            if 0 <= (dir1_file - dir2_file).total_seconds() <= 300:
                dict_gr[str(dir1_file)].append(str(dir2_file))    

        # Sort the dictionaries
    for key, value in sorted(dict_gr.iteritems()):
        dir2_lib.append(key)
        dir1_lib.append(sorted(value))
```

The issue is that path2 and dir2 both properly go to the different folders and grab the necessary filenames, and creating dict_gr will all work well. However, when I go to the part of the script where I sort the dictionaries, the 2nd directory that has been looped over will contain the contents of the first directory. The 3rd looped dictionary will contain the contents of the 1st and 2nd, etc. In other words, they are not matching uniquely with each directory.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, perhaps limit the depth of the nesting?

Answer (score 0):

Overlooked appending to dir2_lib and dir1_lib, needed to initialize these.